# What is the correct way to implement the move() function in this Java Object Oriented code?

Tags: java, oop, superclass

I am going to try this again. I need help. I have apparently done something wrong with my code. I tried asking on here for help, and my question was closed and I was told to go to Code Review. I posted my question on their and they refuse to help because they say I am not following the instructions of the problem I was given. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and if no one is willing to help, how am I supposed to learn? So here I go again, with the question edited so that HOPEFULLY it will pass this time.

I was assigned the following problem:

You've gone back in time to 500BC Athens and Socrates wants you
to build him an app to help classify animals.

1. Build the classes Animal, Cat, and Bug.
2. Define the properties "color" and "leg_number" on the
   relevant and necessary classes. Have them be initialized
   within a constructor.
3. Add the functionality that would allow us to call a method
   "move" with the Cat and Bug classes. Have the method return
   a string "I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!", with the
   "leg_number" being leg_number as set on the class.
4. Add a new class called Bird. Add the property
   "wing_number". Add the functionality that would allow us to
   call a method "move" with the Bird class. Have the method
   return the string "I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!"
   if wing_number doesn't have an applicable value. If
   wing_number does have an applicable value, return the
   string "I'm flying".

My code for that is as follows:

```
public class SocratesApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cat myCat = new Cat("orange", 4);
        int catLegs = myCat.leg_number;
        myCat.move(catLegs);
    
        Bug myBug = new Bug("green", 16);
        int bugLegs = myBug.leg_number;
        myBug.move(bugLegs);
    
        Bird bird1 = new Bird("yellow", 2, 2);
        int bird1Legs = bird1.leg_number;
        int bird1Wings = bird1.wing_number;
        bird1.move(bird1Legs, bird1Wings);
    
        Bird bird2 = new Bird("brown", 2, 0);
        int bird2Legs = bird2.leg_number;
        int bird2Wings = bird2.wing_number;
        bird1.move(bird2Legs, bird2Wings);

    }

}

class Animal {

    private String color;
    private int leg_number;

    public Animal(String color, int leg_number) {
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
    }

    public void move(int leg_number) {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;

    public Cat(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(int leg_number) {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Bug extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;

    public Bug(String color, int leg_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
    }

    @Override
    public void move(int leg_number) {
        System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
    }
}

class Bird extends Animal {
    String color;
    int leg_number;
    int wing_number;

    public Bird(String color, int leg_number, int wing_number) {
        super(color, leg_number);
        this.color = color;
        this.leg_number = leg_number;
        this.wing_number = wing_number;
    }

    public void move(int leg_number, int wing_number) {
        if (wing_number > 0) {
            System.out.println("I'm flying");
        } else {
            System.out.println("I'm moving with " + leg_number + " legs!");
        }
    }
}
```

Someone told me that I am not implementing the move() method as required by the instructions, but they will not tell me what I'm doing wrong. I guess I must not understand the instructions. I need someone to tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to correct it. This is VERY IMPORTANT. Would someone PLEASE help me with this?

Comment: I don't think you really want to pass in the number of legs to the `move()` method: a cat wouldn't move with 89 legs, but your method currently allows that. Remove the parameter, and use the `leg_number` field's value.

Comment: I see there is an error in the problem as I have copied it. It must be because of the problem's use of greater than and less than signs. I will correct it.

Comment: Yes, you were told to go to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) because *this* exchange is for broken code.  Code Review is for working code that needs *opinions* on how it could be made better.   If your code is not working, explain in detail what the error you are having is, what  the expected behavior is, what it is/isn't doing.  We don't need the whole text of the assignment.

Comment: Well it appears that no one from either board is going to help me, so I guess I am just screwed.

Comment: Each object knows how many legs it has, so, as already told, the `move` method shouldn’t have such a parameter at all. Just create a `public void move()` method. Since your `Animal` class does already declare a `private String color;` and a `private int leg_number;` field, there is no need for the subclasses to declare them again. They do already inherit the fields, just make them `protected` instead of `private`, so the subclasses can access them.

Comment: Thank you for that

Comment: "I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and if no one is willing to help, how am I supposed to learn?" You hire a tutor and pay him for his time.  Otherwise, study the links you've been given and expect that it will take a long time and a lot of effort to learn Java.